# Word Cross Game doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, search, mobile, words

I found a word search game on Codepen that works fine on desktop, but when opened on mobile, it doesn't work when I try to highlight the words. Does anybody know if it can be adapted for mobile?

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/collosic/pen/HBtwk

```
      // JavaScript Documentvar pos = [];
  var click = { "startPos": "", "endPos": ""
              };
  var letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                 "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"];

  var words = [ { "word": "BUFFALO", "direction": "N", "start": 254 },
                { "word": "LAKERS", "direction": "SE", "start": 2 },
                { "word": "PRECIPITATE", "direction": "NE", "start": 323 },
                { "word": "CALDRON", "direction": "S", "start": 39 },
                { "word": "MISCIBLE", "direction": "NW", "start": 268 },
                { "word": "AEON", "direction": "E", "start": 132 },
                { "word": "SCRUTINY", "direction": "E", "start": 49 },
                { "word": "CLEANERS", "direction": "S", "start": 137},
                { "word": "SEETHING", "direction": "W", "start": 357 },
                { "word": "MOTH", "direction": "E", "start": 383 },
                { "word": "DOUBLE", "direction": "S", "start": 120 },
                { "word": "CREATURE", "direction": "N", "start": 395 },
                { "word": "GIPSY", "direction": "NW", "start": 340 },
                { "word": "MOBILE", "direction": "W", "start": 98 },
                { "word": "COMPUTER", "direction": "N", "start": 381 },
                { "word": "THEWEB", "direction": "N", "start": 145 },
                { "word": "HORSES", "direction": "E", "start": 6 },
                { "word": "HICKORYJUMP", "direction": "NE", "start": 204 },
                { "word": "CHROME", "direction": "NW", "start": 266},
                { "word": "MULDER", "direction": "S", "start": 41 },
              ];


  // Prepare the wordsearch with random letters and word layout
  $(document).ready(function() {
      // grab the size of the grid.  I used this method in case I need to 
      // scale this word search in the future
      var size = 400; //($(".left").css("width").slice(0, 3) - 20) / 2 ;

      // put random letters on the board
      for (var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          $(".letters").append("<span class='" + (i + 1) + "'>" + 
                              getRandomLetter() + "</span>");
      }

      // insert the words onto the board
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          words[i].end = words[i].start;
          displayWord(words[i]);
          // save the start and end of each word for word checking later
          pos[i] = { "start": words[i].start, "end": words[i].end };
          $(".words").append("<span class='" + (i) + "'>" +  
                              words[i].word + "</span>");   
      }

      $("#menu").on("mouseup", function() {
          $(this).css( {"display": "none"})
          $("#main").slideDown("slow", function() {
          })
      });
  })

  function getRandomLetter() {
      return letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
  }

  function displayWord(w) {
      for (var j = 0; j < w.word.length; j++){
          if (w.direction == "N") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end -= 20;
          }
          if (w.direction == "NE") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end -= 19;
          }
          if (w.direction == "E") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end += 1;
          }
          if (w.direction == "SE") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end += 21;
          }
          if (w.direction == "S") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end += 20;
          }
          if (w.direction == "SW") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end += 19;
          }
          if (w.direction == "W") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end -= 1;
          }
          if (w.direction == "NW") {
              $(".letters").find("." + w.end).text(w.word[j]);
              if (j + 1 != w.word.length) w.end -= 21;
          }
      }
  }


  // start of x & y, end of x & y.  
  var sX, sY, eX, eY, canvas, ctx, height, width, diff;
  var r = 14;
  var n = Math.sqrt((r * r) / 2);
  var strokeColor = "black";
  var isMouseDown = false;
  var mouseMoved = false;

  $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#c").on("mousedown mouseup mousemove mouseleave", function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          //console.log(e);
          if (e.type == "mousedown") {
              setCanvas("c");           
              isMouseDown = true;

        // Used for Firefox
              sX = e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left;
              sY = e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top;
              // adjust the center of the arc 
              sX -= (sX % 20);
              sY -= (sY % 20);
              if (!(sX % 40)) sX += 20;
              if (!(sY % 40)) sY += 20;

              setPos(sX, sY, "start");
              draw(e.type);
          } 
          else if (e.type == "mousemove") {
              if (isMouseDown) {
                  mouseMoved = true;
                  eX = e.offsetX || e.clientX - $(e.target).offset().left;
                  eY = e.offsetY || e.clientY - $(e.target).offset().top;
                  draw(e.type);
              }
          } 
          else if (e.type == "mouseup") {
              isMouseDown = false;
              ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              if (mouseMoved) {
                  mouseMoved = false;

                  eX -= eX % 20;
                  eY -= eY % 20;
                  if (!(eX % 40)) eX += 20;
                  if (!(eY % 40)) eY += 20;

                  // draw the last line and clear the canvas to check and see if its the 
                  // correct word
                  draw(e.type);
                  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                  // if a correct word has been highlighted change the canvas to 
                  // the permanent one and redraw the arcs and lines.  Then scratch the 
                  // word on the right.
                  if (checkWord()) {
                      setCanvas("a");
                      draw(e.type);
                      scratchWord();
                      // Check if the game is over
                      if(isEndOfGame()) {
                          alert("Good job!");
                      }
                  }

              }
          } 
          else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
              isMouseDown = false;
              draw(e.type);
          }

      });
  })

  // This function is called when lines need to be drawn on the game
  function draw(f) {
      // used to draw an arc.  takes in two numbers that represent the beginning
      // and end of the arc
      function drawArc(xArc, yArc, num1, num2) {
          ctx.lineWidth = 2;
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(xArc, yArc, r, num1 * Math.PI, num2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
          ctx.stroke();
      }

      // used to draw the two lines around letters
      function drawLines(mX1, mY1, lX1, lY1, mX2, mY2, lX2, lY2) {
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(mX1, mY1);
          ctx.lineTo(lX1, lY1);
          ctx.moveTo(mX2, mY2);
          ctx.lineTo(lX2, lY2);
          ctx.stroke();
      }
      // Check and see what event occured and create the action that belongs to that 
      // event.
      if (f == "mousedown"){
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
          drawArc(sX, sY, 0, 2);
      }
      else if (f == "mousemove" || f == "mouseup") {
          /* 
          This is to show the rise over run I used to get the limits for 
          all eight directions.  This tells the conditionals when to activiate
          the lines and in which direction.
          rise = (sY - eY) * Math.sqrt(6);
          run = sX - eX;
           */     
          limit = ((sY - eY) * Math.sqrt(6)) / (sX - eX);
          // UP
          if ((limit > 6 || limit < -6) && eY < sY) {
              // clear the canvas
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              drawArc(sX, sY, 0, 1); // draw bottom arc
              drawArc(sX, eY, 1, 2); // draw top arc

              // draw the two lines that connect the bottom and the top arcs
              drawLines(sX + r, sY, sX + r, eY, sX - r, sY, sX -r, eY); 

              // if the player is selecting this as the last letter set its position 
              // for wordcheck
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX, eY, "end");    
          }
          // DOWN
          if ((limit < -6 || limit > 6) && eY > sY) {
              // clear the canvas
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              drawArc(sX, sY, 1, 2); 
              drawArc(sX, eY, 0, 1); 
              drawLines(sX + r, sY, sX + r, eY, sX - r, sY, sX -r, eY);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX, eY, "end");        
          }             
          // LEFT
          if ((limit < 1 && limit > -1) && eX < sX) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              drawArc(sX, sY, 1.5, 0.5);
              drawArc(eX, sY, 0.5, 1.5);
              drawLines(sX, sY - r, eX, sY -r, sX, sY + r, eX, sY + r);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(eX, sY, "end");
          } 
          // RIGHT
          if ((limit < 1 && limit > -1) && eX > sX) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              drawArc(sX, sY, 0.5, 1.5);
              drawArc(eX, sY, 1.5, 0.5);
              drawLines(sX, sY - r, eX, sY -r, sX, sY + r, eX, sY + r);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(eX, sY, "end");
          }
          /* 
          This is for the NW diagonal lines it requires a special number 
          n that is the adjacent lengths of a 45-45-90 triangle needed to draw these
          lines.  It also creates a diff for the difference between the 
          start and the end of the arcs 
          */
          // NW
          if ((limit > 1 && limit < 6) && (eX < sX && eY < sY)) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              diff = sX - eX;
              drawArc(sX, sY, 1.75, 0.75);
              drawArc(sX - diff, sY - diff, 0.75, 1.75);
              drawLines(sX + n, sY - n, sX + n - diff, sY - n - diff, 
                        sX - n, sY + n, sX - n - diff, sY + n - diff);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX - diff, sY - diff, "end");
          } 

          // NE
          if ((limit < -1 && limit > -6) && (eX > sX && eY < sY)) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              diff = sX - eX;
              drawArc(sX, sY, 0.25, 1.25);
              drawArc(sX - diff, sY + diff, 1.25, 0.25);
              drawLines(sX + n, sY + n, sX + n - diff, sY + n + diff, 
                        sX - n, sY - n, sX - n - diff, sY - n + diff);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX - diff, sY + diff, "end");
          } 
          // SW
          if ((limit < -1 && limit > -6) && (eX < sX && eY > sY)) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              diff = sX - eX;
              drawArc(sX, sY, 1.25, 0.25);
              drawArc(sX - diff, sY + diff, 0.25, 1.25);
              drawLines(sX + n, sY + n, sX + n - diff, sY + n + diff, 
                        sX - n, sY - n, sX - n - diff, sY - n + diff);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX - diff, sY + diff, "end");
          } 
          // SE
          if ((limit > 1 && limit < 6) && (eX > sX && eY > sY)) {
              if (f == "mousemove") ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
              diff = sX - eX;
              drawArc(sX, sY, 0.75, 1.75);
              drawArc(sX - diff, sY - diff, 1.75, 0.75);
              drawLines(sX + n, sY - n, sX + n - diff, sY - n - diff, 
                        sX - n, sY + n, sX - n - diff, sY + n - diff);
              if (f == "mouseup") setPos(sX - diff, sY - diff, "end");
          } 
      }

      else if (f == "mouseleave") {
          setCanvas("c");
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
      }
  }


  // change the canvas between the bottom and top layer
  function setCanvas(id) {
      canvas = document.getElementById(id);
      ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      width = canvas.width;
      height = canvas.height;
  }


  // set the offsets to numbers that match the class names of each letter
  function setPos(x, y, loc) {
      tX = Math.floor((x / 8) / 5 ) + 1;
      tY = Math.floor((y / 8) / 5 ) + 1;
      if (loc == "start") click.startPos = (tY - 1) * 20 + tX;
      else click.endPos = (tY - 1) * 20 + tX;
  }


  // verify if the word chosen is the correct one. If a player decides
  // to highlight a word starting from last letter to first this function
  // will also support that ability
  function checkWord() {
      // clears the pos array so that a player cannot highlight the same word twice
      function clearPos(p) {
          p.start = p.end = 0;
          return true;
      }
      // user highlights from first letter to last
      if (pos.some(function(o) { return o.start === click.startPos &&
                                 o.end === click.endPos && clearPos(o); })) {
          return true;
      }
      // if user highlights from last letter to first
      else if (pos.some(function(o) { return o.start === click.endPos &&
                                      o.end === click.startPos && clearPos(o); })) {
          return true;
      }
      else return false;
  }

  // scratch the word on the right out when the word is found on the left
  function scratchWord() {
      for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
          if ((click.startPos === words[i].start && click.endPos === words[i].end) ||
              (click.startPos === words[i].end && click.endPos === words[i].start)) {
              // little hack here
              $(".words").find("." + i).addClass("strike");     
          }
      }
      // check if the game is over

  }

  function isEndOfGame(){
      return pos.every(function(o) { return o.start === 0 && o.end === 0; });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On mobile, there is no mouse. The code within the Codepen link works by binding to the `mouseup`/`mousedown` events, so the events will never fire on mobile.

Typically the `touchstart` / `touchend` events are used alongside mouse events in JavaScript to bridge the missing mouse control, but the events work slightly differently and therefore is a non-trivial task to implement.

Read more about mouse events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Read more about touch events here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Touch_events